# Why doesn't my SIM card does allow a connection to this network?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, connection-issues, htc-desire-z, mobile-network

In Android 2.2 from a HTC Desire Z I am frequently finding my phone disconnected from my mobile provider.

When I select my provider from the Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks -> Network operators -> Search networks -> <My Provider> I get the message "Your SIM card does not allow a connection to this network".

The only fix I can find is to restart my phone. Problem appears to widely affect Android phones.

Answer (score 1):

It appears several sites suggest preventing the phone from using 3G. I have gone into Settings -> Wireless & network -> Mobile networks -> Network Mode -> GSM only.

This appears to have fixed the issue for me. Of course this wouldn't be a solution for anybody who relies on mobile data (but my provider charges so much for data that I'm wi-fi only).

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of this error message is that the country in which you are may require your IMEI to be registered with the government - if you have already registered it check whether it has been removed from the relevent list (Turkey in my case so I checked http://imei.tk.gov.tr/tr/imeisorgu.php and found it had been removed) and contact the relevent government official to get it put back on.

I don't understand why the error message refers to the SIM card - it misled me and wasted hours of my time as the problem in my case was nothing to do with the SIM card. I assume this is an Android error message - I think the message should be improved and presumably mention "IMEI" but I am not sure exactly what it should say. Perhaps others in this forum can suggest a better error message.